# How to identify dates where a certain condition is met? [In python]

Tags: python, pandas, database

I have a data frame with the min, max prices for each hour of a day. The duration of the dataset is about one year. I have attached an example. You can run the code snippet to generate the table. Sorry I am new to Stackoverflow, I don't how to insert tables here yet.

I want to isolate the dates where Consume(Min) price < 0 for atleast 4 times, between 9h to 16h for that date {lets name this condition 1}. I want a output which consists of all the dates (with all 24 hrs) where condition 1 is met.

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html><head><title></title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Style-Type" content="text/css">
<style type="text/css"><!--
body {
  margin: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
}
/* ========== Text Styles ========== */
hr { color: #000000}
body, table /* Normal text */
{
 font-size: 10pt;
 font-family: 'Courier New';
 font-style: normal;
 font-weight: normal;
 color: #000000;
 text-decoration: none;
}
span.rvts1 /* Heading */
{
 font-family: 'Arial';
 font-weight: bold;
 color: #0000ff;
}
span.rvts2 /* Subheading */
{
 font-family: 'Arial';
 font-weight: bold;
 color: #000080;
}
span.rvts3 /* Keywords */
{
 font-family: 'Arial';
 font-style: italic;
 color: #800000;
}
a.rvts4, span.rvts4 /* Jump 1 */
{
 color: #008000;
 text-decoration: underline;
}
a.rvts5, span.rvts5 /* Jump 2 */
{
 font-family: 'Arial';
 color: #008000;
 text-decoration: underline;
}
/* ========== Para Styles ========== */
p,ul,ol /* Paragraph Style */
{
 text-align: left;
 text-indent: 0px;
 padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
 margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
}
.rvps1 /* Centered */
{
 text-align: center;
}
--></style>
</head>
<body>

<p><br></p>
<div><table width="100%" border=1 cellpadding=1 cellspacing=2 style="background-color: #ffffff;">
<tr valign=top>
<td style="border-style: inset;">
<p><span class=rvts1>Date (CET)</span></p>
</td>
<td style="border-style: inset;">
<p><span class=rvts1>Consume (Min)</span></p>
</td>
<td style="border-style: inset;">
<p><span class=rvts1>Feed (Max)</span></p>
</td>
</tr>
<tr valign=top>
<td style="border-style: inset;"><br>
</td>
<td style="border-style: inset;">
<p>EUR</p>
</td>
<td style="border-style: inset;">
<p>EUR</p>
</td>
</tr>
<tr valign=top>
<td style="border-style: inset;">
<p>[24/03/2021 11:00]</p>
</td>
<td style="border-style: inset;">
<p>-159.02</p>
</td>
<td style="border-style: inset;">
<p>-159.02</p>
</td>
</tr>
<tr valign=top>
<td style="border-style: inset;">
<p>[24/03/2021 12:00]</p>
</td>
<td style="border-style: inset;">
<p>-159</p>
</td>
<td style="border-style: inset;">
<p>-53.89</p>
</td>
</tr>
<tr valign=top>
<td style="border-style: inset;">
<p>[24/03/2021 13:00]</p>
</td>
<td style="border-style: inset;">
<p>-0.33</p>
</td>
<td style="border-style: inset;">
<p>44.7</p>
</td>
</tr>
<tr valign=top>
<td style="border-style: inset;">
<p>[24/03/2021 14:00]</p>
</td>
<td style="border-style: inset;">
<p>-150.32</p>
</td>
<td style="border-style: inset;">
<p>44.7</p>
</td>
</tr>
<tr valign=top>
<td style="border-style: inset;">
<p>[24/03/2021 15:00]</p>
</td>
<td style="border-style: inset;">
<p>-3.9</p>
</td>
<td style="border-style: inset;">
<p>39.89</p>
</td>
</tr>
<tr valign=top>
<td style="border-style: inset;">
<p>[24/03/2021 16:00]</p>
</td>
<td style="border-style: inset;">
<p>12.01</p>
</td>
<td style="border-style: inset;">
<p>52.2</p>
</td>
</tr>
<tr valign=top>
<td style="border-style: inset;">
<p>[24/03/2021 17:00]</p>
</td>
<td style="border-style: inset;">
<p>34.31</p>
</td>
<td style="border-style: inset;">
<p>73.03</p>
</td>
</tr>
<tr valign=top>
<td style="border-style: inset;">
<p>[24/03/2021 18:00]</p>
</td>
<td style="border-style: inset;">
<p>-74.57</p>
</td>
<td style="border-style: inset;">
<p>54.21</p>
</td>
</tr>
<tr valign=top>
<td style="border-style: inset;">
<p>[24/03/2021 19:00]</p>
</td>
<td style="border-style: inset;">
<p>53.32</p>
</td>
<td style="border-style: inset;">
<p>64</p>
</td>
</tr>
<tr valign=top>
<td style="border-style: inset;">
<p>[24/03/2021 20:00]</p>
</td>
<td style="border-style: inset;">
<p>36.89</p>
</td>
<td style="border-style: inset;">
<p>423.58</p>
</td>
</tr>
<tr valign=top>
<td style="border-style: inset;">
<p>[24/03/2021 21:00]</p>
</td>
<td style="border-style: inset;">
<p>39.89</p>
</td>
<td style="border-style: inset;">
<p>54.14</p>
</td>
</tr>
<tr valign=top>
<td style="border-style: inset;">
<p>[24/03/2021 22:00]</p>
</td>
<td style="border-style: inset;">
<p>33.89</p>
</td>
<td style="border-style: inset;">
<p>53.97</p>
</td>
</tr>
<tr valign=top>
<td style="border-style: inset;">
<p>[24/03/2021 23:00]</p>
</td>
<td style="border-style: inset;">
<p>33</p>
</td>
<td style="border-style: inset;">
<p>53.73</p>
</td>
</tr>
<tr valign=top>
<td style="border-style: inset;">
<p>[25/03/2021 00:00]</p>
</td>
<td style="border-style: inset;">
<p>42.72</p>
</td>
<td style="border-style: inset;">
<p>45.84</p>
</td>
</tr>
<tr valign=top>
<td style="border-style: inset;">
<p>[25/03/2021 01:00]</p>
</td>
<td style="border-style: inset;">
<p>42.98</p>
</td>
<td style="border-style: inset;">
<p>46.58</p>
</td>
</tr>
<tr valign=top>
<td style="border-style: inset;">
<p>[25/03/2021 02:00]</p>
</td>
<td style="border-style: inset;">
<p>45.82</p>
</td>
<td style="border-style: inset;">
<p>48.1</p>
</td>
</tr>
<tr valign=top>
<td style="border-style: inset;">
<p>[25/03/2021 03:00]</p>
</td>
<td style="border-style: inset;">
<p>45.82</p>
</td>
<td style="border-style: inset;">
<p>51.27</p>
</td>
</tr>
<tr valign=top>
<td style="border-style: inset;">
<p>[25/03/2021 04:00]</p>
</td>
<td style="border-style: inset;">
<p>45.81</p>
</td>
<td style="border-style: inset;">
<p>49.51</p>
</td>
</tr>
<tr valign=top>
<td style="border-style: inset;">
<p>[25/03/2021 05:00]</p>
</td>
<td style="border-style: inset;">
<p>45.47</p>
</td>
<td style="border-style: inset;">
<p>53.81</p>
</td>
</tr>
<tr valign=top>
<td style="border-style: inset;">
<p>[25/03/2021 06:00]</p>
</td>
<td style="border-style: inset;">
<p>38.57</p>
</td>
<td style="border-style: inset;">
<p>53.42</p>
</td>
</tr>
<tr valign=top>
<td style="border-style: inset;">
<p>[25/03/2021 07:00]</p>
</td>
<td style="border-style: inset;">
<p>36.44</p>
</td>
<td style="border-style: inset;">
<p>54.34</p>
</td>
</tr>
<tr valign=top>
<td style="border-style: inset;">
<p>[25/03/2021 08:00]</p>
</td>
<td style="border-style: inset;">
<p>36.44</p>
</td>
<td style="border-style: inset;">
<p>40.51</p>
</td>
</tr>
<tr valign=top>
<td style="border-style: inset;">
<p>[25/03/2021 09:00]</p>
</td>
<td style="border-style: inset;">
<p>39.44</p>
</td>
<td style="border-style: inset;">
<p>61.15</p>
</td>
</tr>
<tr valign=top>
<td style="border-style: inset;">
<p>[25/03/2021 10:00]</p>
</td>
<td style="border-style: inset;">
<p>44.46</p>
</td>
<td style="border-style: inset;">
<p>87.73</p>
</td>
</tr>
<tr valign=top>
<td style="border-style: inset;">
<p>[25/03/2021 11:00]</p>
</td>
<td style="border-style: inset;">
<p>44.29</p>
</td>
<td style="border-style: inset;">
<p>45.02</p>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>

</body></html>
```

Comment: can you tell me the output of `type(df.loc[0,'Date (CET)'])`

Comment: The output is this :  pandas._libs.tslibs.timestamps.Timestamp. I use a function to convert the column into datetime

Comment: After converting it to datetime, the format is yyyy-mm-dd HH:MM:SS

Comment: @AnuragDabas I figured it out! I just isolated the dates for the condition into `listt` and then used `dfinal = df[df['Date (CET)'].dt.date.isin(listt)]`  to get those dates

Comment: Great...Happy for you that you got solution of your question  :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this library

```py
from lxml import html
```

Used API for writing in HTML , XML , CSS
You can get information from the site according to the class name or idea using (xpath)

Example:

```py
time = tree.xpath('//date/text()')
```

Then you can filter the information with the help of array ( `time[0]` or  `time[0:4]`)
Or you can save the information in the database by (SQL) Then arrange them.

Also after saving the information you can with

```py
import time

time.time()
```

Get and sort the latest date and time, then compare with your data.

Comment: FYI their question is about pandas dataframes. They put the sample data in an html table, but the actual question is not about parsing html.